# .vimrc sourcing another leads to plugin errors

Tags: vim, vimrc, bashrc

Since vim or vim-pymode does not seem to work with both python 2 and 3 at the same time I thought I make an alias for my newly compiled vim version specially for developing python 3. So I added this alias:

```
alias vim3="vim-py3 -u /home/jim/.vimrc-py3"
```

My .vimrc-py3 should have everything from the original .vimrc, just one additional line is there. So what I tried was:

```
source $HOME/.vimrc
let g:pymode_python = 'python3'
```

While vim and vim-py3 starts fine, vim3 shows a long list of plugin errors:

```
Error detected while processing /home/jim/.vimrc:
line    1:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
E15: Invalid expression: pathogen#infect()
line  146:
E117: Unknown function: airline#section#create
E15: Invalid expression: airline#section#create(['%='])
line  149:
E117: Unknown function: airline#section#create
E15: Invalid expression: airline#section#create([])
line  150:
E117: Unknown function: airline#section#create
E15: Invalid expression: airline#section#create([])
line  151:
E117: Unknown function: airline#section#create
E15: Invalid expression: airline#section#create(['hunks']) 
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Do I source the original .vimrc wrongly?

Comment: Maybe try asking on http://vi.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: What about `alias vim3="vim -Nu /home/jim/.vimrc-py3"`?

Comment: @romainl That works thank you, do you want to add it as answer?